# allow requests from specific url

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I have controller

```
public class BilingController : Controller
{
    …
[HttpPost]
    public string Result (string data)
{
…
}

…
}
```

Method **Result** can be caused only by foreign service **process.anypayservice.com**

How can I check url, is request from service **process.anypayservice.com** or other service?

Or allow only this url - **process.payservice.com** for  method Result call

Any attribute or I should write custom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [`HTTP_REFERER`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) header, but note that it can be easily spoofed.

A better approach is to use some sort of token that can be passed in to your service for authentication.